# Pre-built audio player UI on iphone?

Tags: iphone, audio, avaudioplayer

My boss seems to think there's a way to play audio files via a built-in QT interface that comes up with a modal UI, much like address book framework does.

Also, the mail app pops up a QT modal player to play attached audio files and then hides itself when done.

I've done a good 2 hours of research and I cannot find any pre-built UI for playing audio. I understand that I can do it via `AVAudioPlayer`, but that still requires I build a custom UI, which is fine, but we're looking for visual familiarity and consistency.

I just now found `MPMusicPlayerController`, but it appears to only play itunes media, not media from file paths.

So, is there a pre-built audio player UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MPMoviePlayerController` can also be used to play audio files (although it's not recommended):

```
MPMoviePlayerController *mPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.freeaudioclips.com/music1/Sound_Effects/austinmail.wav"]];
// Show Audio player just to test it out
if (mPlayer)
{
    [mPlayer play];
}
```

Read [Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MPMoviePlayerController/initWithContentURL:) and for more details.

Comment: Just curious .. why is it not recommended to use the MPMoviePlayerController?

Comment: I would say now there is no technical reason not to other than it seems counter-intuitive since the class is labelled "MoviePlayer".